# Surface integral definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area

If I have a surface $S$ generated by a $C$ curve, say $S: r(t,s)=(t,t^2,s)$ with $(t,s)$ at $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, then applying the surface integral definition as follows, projecting on the XY plane (why not?), the area gives 0.

[image]

Could it be that these definitions require that the region of integration has interior not emptiness?

Comment: You mean $U=\Omega$ and this should be an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Yes,the author of the book says  $U$ must be contained in the open set $\Omega.$  My mistake was to think that one can integrate on the projection of the surface  $S$ in the $XY$ plane (integrate on the $C$ curve) and rather one integrates on the domain of the parameterization (which corresponds to the projection). In the example I give, of course, the  cilinder $S$  cannot be parameterised in such a way that the parameterization domain is in the XY plane. That's how I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {\partial r}{\partial s} = (0,0,1)\\
\frac {\partial r}{\partial t} = (1,2t,0)\\
dS = \frac {\partial r}{\partial s} \times\frac {\partial r}{\partial t} = (-2t,1,0)\\
\|dS\| = \sqrt {4t^2 + 1} \ ds\ dt$

$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \sqrt {4t^2 + 1} \ ds \ dt\\
\frac 14 \sinh^{-1}(2) + \frac 12 \sqrt 5$

Comment: Ah ok. I understand, I was wrong: I saw it as a double integral over a curve. Thanks